# IsCompleted Checkbox for case milestone

Tags: casemilestone

We populate the value for "Completion Date" for a case milestone through code. So when a case milestone got its completion date, its "IsCompleted" checkbox is getting checked automatically..
Could this be a standard functionality of checking or there might be any action specified in the org?
Any suggestions please...
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: You can just add this checkbox as a formula which check if the completion date is null.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But am unable to see the field("IsCompleted" of CaseMilestone) as its showing "Insufficient Privileges" Though am the system admin.

Comment: Ok I realized that I didn't understand your question. If I understand well, this is already a standard functionality. The completion date check automatically the IsCompleted field. So what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Yes.You got it right now.. I was worrying about how the IsCompleted field is checked....So the completion date checks the IsCompleted field "Automatically"..... Am I Right..?

Answer (score 0):

In Salesforce, `CaseMilestone` is a special object. In order to complete the specific `Milestone(s)`, you need to just populate the **"Completion Date"** only (as you are already doing it through trigger logic), salesforce internally takes care of updating the CheckBox value to true. This is as per design.

You can complete the single milestones or many milestones at a time. You just need  tweak the completion logic to suffice for all milestones.